archlinxu - xorg.conf for X11
I am using archlinux with kde and X11.
I have two monitors, one connected to nvidia and one connected to built-in intel gpu. The nvidia monitor has been recognized properly, while the intel monitor is all black and when I pass the mouse, it has an X on it. boot information and boot option are properly printed on the intel monitor, login is performed by the gpu
Below I list my configuration.
I have no kernel parameter except
options nvidia_drm modeset=1 

I have a single xorg.conf file
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
        Option "XkbLayout" "it"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "Rotate" "left"  # Rotating the built-in screen
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"  # Adjust the BusID as necessary
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Additional information
lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)

and
lscpu 
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   8
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-7
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
    CPU family:           6

grep -iE 'error|warning' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

and just one monitor is detected
xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-0 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  HDMI-0

I have try different driver in the xorg.conf file, but I cannot understand the problem
In addition to this problem, second screen is not rotated.
